# Windows/XBOX 360 Programming

Tags: windows, xna, xbox

Is there some way of programming a game for windows / xbox 360 outside XNA Game Studio. I assume that for Windows a just need to download DirectX and install it into visual studio but for xbox i'm not sure.

PS: If the way is XDK (for Xbox)  is possible for an Indie Games Developer to get his hands on that SDK.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you refer to Xbox One in the title, when you're asking about Windows/360?

Comment: According to Microsoft, every Xbox One will contain a development kit baked-in...

Comment: sorry about that, I just change it

Answer (score 0):

To self-publish a game to the Xbox 360 Xbox Live Indie Games section XNA is your only option. Licensed developers who publish either full retail games or Xbox Live Arcade games have more options but those are developers who either have a publisher working with them or Microsoft is working with them as a publisher, which I would assume is not the case for you.

As a side note, it's still the solution for 360 indie publishing, but XNA is not being actively developed any more and does not target new Windows store applications for Windows 8 or Windows 8.1. As such it works for 360 Indie games and Windows desktop games, but you you'll have to port your game to move it to modern windows platforms and there is currently no plans to support XNA on other platforms moving forward.